# ReactNative animation is not working after the api call

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

here is my code.

```
  const actionButtonsAnimated = new Animated.Value(0);
  const animated = new Animated.Value(255);

  const animateTrendingCardSheet = () => {
   Animated.timing(animated, {
     toValue: 0,
     duration: 1500,
     useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
    Animated.timing(actionButtonsAnimated, {
      toValue: -180,
      duration: 1000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };
```

```
<Animated.View
        style={[
          {
            transform: [{ translateY: actionButtonsAnimated }],
          },
        ]}
      >
        <MainActionButtons />
      </Animated.View>

      <Animated.View
        style={[
          {
            transform: [{ translateY: animated }],
            width: "100%",
            position: "absolute",
            bottom: 0,
          },
        ]}
      >
        <View style={styles.trendingCards}>
          <Text h5 center color={colors.trendingText}>
            Trending in your area...
          </Text>

          <View style={styles.flatlistWrapper}>
            <FlatList
              horizontal={true}
              data={trendingCards}
              renderItem={({ item }) => <TrendingCardComponent card={item} />}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </Animated.View>
```

so if i call the `animateTrendingCardSheet` function inside useEffect like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
animateTrendingCardSheet()
}, [])
```

it works as expected but once i put it in a condition that it should be called after the API call has been finished it does not work at all if i again save the file it hot reload animation works

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loadTrendingCard) {
      animateTrendingCardSheet();
    }
  }, [loadTrendingCard]);
```

Comment: The function is animating; it just that after the first time animation call you the toValue is the same as the current value; so it looks like nothing is happening; but if you set it toggle between the toValues it works fine https://snack.expo.dev/Mw7PViDQy

Comment: Maybe before you start your API call you set the animation values to their initial state, and then when the api call completes call the animation?

Comment: Well that would look weird, but if you animated the views' opacity to zero first, reset the animation values, when api call complete set opacity to one, and the run the animation it might look more natural

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that after the first call to `animateTrendingCardSheet` the toValue that you are animating to is the current value of your Animated variables; so it looks like nothing is happening. You can counteract this by resetting your animation variables before calling your animation function:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Animated,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const MainActionButtons = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
      }}>
      <TouchableOpacity>Btn 1</TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity>Btn 2</TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity>Btn 3</TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity>Btn 4</TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const TrendingCardComponent = ({ card }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Text>{card.title}</Text>
      <Text>{card.message}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const trendingCards = [
  { title: 'A Cool Card', message: 'A cool message' },
  { title: 'Card 1', message: 'A cool message' },
  { title: 'A Cool Card', message: 'A cool message' },
  { title: 'A Cool Card', message: 'A cool message' },
];

const initialActionButton = 0;
const initialAnimated = 255;
export default function App() {
  const actionButtonsAnimated = new Animated.Value(initialActionButton);
  const animated = new Animated.Value(initialAnimated);
  const opacity = new Animated.Value(1)

  const onApiCall = ()=>{
    // set opacity to 0
    Animated.timing(opacity,{toValue:0,duration:500}).start(()=>{
      // when view is invisible do resets
      animated.setValue(initialAnimated)
      actionButtonsAnimated.setValue(initialActionButton)
      Animated.timing(opacity,{toValue:1,duration:500}).start()
      animateTrendingCardSheet()
    })
  }

  const animateTrendingCardSheet = () => {
    Animated.timing(animated, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 1500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
    Animated.timing(actionButtonsAnimated, {
      toValue:  -180 ,
      duration: 1000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };
  // React.useEffect(() => {
  //   animateTrendingCardSheet();
  // }, []);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title="Simulate API call" onPress={onApiCall}/>
        
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          {
            transform: [{ translateY: actionButtonsAnimated }],
            opacity
          },
        ]}>
        <MainActionButtons />
      </Animated.View>

      <Animated.View
        style={[
          {
            transform: [{ translateY: animated }],
            width: '100%',
            position: 'absolute',
            bottom: 0,
            opacity
          },
        ]}>
        <View style={styles.trendingCards}>
          <Text>Trending in your area...</Text>
          <View style={styles.flatlistWrapper}>
            <FlatList
              style={{ flex: 1 }}
              horizontal={true}
              data={trendingCards}
              renderItem={({ item }) => <TrendingCardComponent card={item} />}
            />
          </View>
        </View>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  flatlistWrapper: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 200,
  },
});
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.dev/OaZk7YWgaY)

Comment: Actually just resetting to the defaults without going invisible isnt as bad as I thought https://snack.expo.dev/qTiceAjLM

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is good but it does not solve my problem, its all due to a stupid mistake, the issue was i was setting the state before calling the animation call function, as the state changes and it interfere the animation i had to use useRef like this.

```
const actionButtonsAnimated = useRef(new Animated.Value(initialActionButton)).current;

const animated = useRef(new Animated.Value(initialAnimated)).current;
```

it reference the state and animation works as expected.